# NodeJS... Saving JSON to a Variable

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, require

I'm a bit of a newbie to NodeJS, but I've looked around all over and can't seem to find a solution to my problem below. I'm sure it's something simple, but thanks in advance for all help you can give me!

I'm trying to make a simple JSON scraper via NodeJS. All I need is for JSON to be stored to a variable. The problem is, I'm using Require, and their example just logs it to console. I've tried adding a variable after it's logging to the console, but I'm just getting undefined. Here's my code below, it's pretty simplistic so far :)

```
//  var jsonVariable; Doesn't work, shown as a test
function getJSON(url){
    var request = require("request")

    request({
    url: url,
    json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {

    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log(body) // Print the json response
        //return body;  This doesn't work, nor does making a global variable called json and assigning it here. Any ideas?
        //jsonVariable = body; // This also doesn't work, returning undefined even after I've called the function with valid JSON
    }
})
}
```

Once again, thanks so much for any help you can give me :)

Comment: When you `return body`, you are returning it to the  `function (error, response, body)` callback and not actually to the `getJSON` function

Comment: i don't get it, the json IS in a variable, `body`. add a callback if you need it somewhere else.

Comment: `jsonVariable = body` works. But it is set at some future time after you call the function. To prove that it works check the value of `jsonVariable` at some future time using `setTimeout`. What this means is that you can never, ever, ever, ever (I can't stress it enough), ever return a value from an async function. What you need to do instead is pass in a callback to **receive** the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the `request` method is asynchronous, but you're trying to synchronously return a result.  You'll need to either make a synchronous request (which doesn't appear to be possible with the `request` package you're using), or else pass a callback function to be called when the request responds successfully.  e.g.:

```
var request = require("request")

function getJSON(url, callback) {
  request({
    url: url,
    json: true
  }, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      callback(body);
    }
  });
}

getJSON('http://example.com/foo.json', function (body) {
  console.log('we have the body!', body);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use 'return body' where does it return to?  That function is being called as a parameter to the request() function.  You also cannot define a variable in your anonymous function because you will not have access to it outside of that scope.

What you need to do is define a variable outside of `function getJSON()` and then save body to that.

e.g.,

```
var result;

function getJSON(url){
  var request = require("request")

  request({
    url: url,
    json: true
    }, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        result = body; 
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: Better yet, he could have a callback function as a parameter to the `getJSON` function and call it when the request is successful because otherwise he will never know when the global body variable is set i.e. when the request finished

Comment: That is a good idea, or he could namespace his outputs into an object somewhere too.  If he's scraping he'll conceivably be getting a fair amount of data.

It's hard to say exactly though without knowing what else he is trying to do.  Side-effects and global variables are poor practice, so my approach can surely be improved upon.

Comment: This is not working for me :( I guess a callback would be a good idea. I assume this function would be called right where we're assigning result to body, correct?

Comment: Edit: My apologies for being vague - even after calling this function, it's returning undefined.

Comment: @FinnC: Don't return. It doesn't work that way. The variable is actually set but as some future time after you call getJSON. To prove it to yourself check the value of the variable after some `setTimeout`. For example, `setTimeout` 10 seconds or so and inside that setTimeout check the value of the variable. The only way for you to use the value is to pass in a callback.

Comment: @slebetman I've figured that out with a few random tests, my real issue is getting to use a callback. I'm fine with doing this in Javascript, it's just converting my method to work with Node is really confusing me for some reason :(

Comment: Check out Matt Huggins' answer, its use of a callback is better practice.  As far as why this isn't working, I don't see why it isn't... if you keep the console.log in, it still fires, correct?  The function attached to request is itself a callback that triggers on receipt of a response.  Keep the log in and ensure that it fires.  (Maybe the status code is off?)

Comment: Yep, I have been keeping the log in. What I have inside would be the console.log(body);, then the result = body.  If I call getJSON, then console.log(result), I'll get the correct JSON text, but it will state that result is undefined.

Comment: Awesome, Matt's answer worked great. Marked as solution!